# How do i calculate the progress reporting of backgroundworker to a progressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a progressBar1 in the designer.
And i have a loop that i'm reporting the progress but only the user state not the int.

```
while (index != -1)
            {
                string firstTag = "<div class=\"CatLinkContainer\">";
                string endTag = "\" href";
                index = forums.IndexOf(firstTag, index1);

                if (index == -1)
                    continue;

                var secondIndex = forums.IndexOf(endTag, index);

                result = forums.Substring(index + firstTag.Length + 12, secondIndex - (index + firstTag.Length - 50));
                if (result.Contains("forumPage"))
                {
                    int index2 = result.IndexOf("\" href=\"http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/forumPage.aspx?forum");
                    result = result.Remove(index2);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    countResults++;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, result);
                    forumsNames.Add(result);
                }

                index1 = index + 1;
            }
```

The reporting of the result is working fine.
But now i'm reporting to the progressBar1 0.
I want to calculate somehow the progress and report also to the progressBar1 the percentages.

I added countResults variable int and i did countResults++;

For example in this case there are 33 result items to report the question is how do i calculate so it will get to the 100% ?
In other cases could be 1 items to report or 122.

In the backgroundworker progresschanged event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

The UserState reporting is working fine.
But now how do i calculate to report the ProgressPercentage ?

Answer (score 1):

You report back a progress percentage:

```
 backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, result);
```

This should be a percentage between 0 and 100. To do that, you have to know how much work is still to be done. That means, before doing the work, you count or estimate the work that needs to be done (What number of strings contain the substring you're looking for). When you have a number for that, you can, in the loop, divide your current count by the estimate and report that number back in `ReportProgress`.

Comment: Robert i didn't understand. I know in this case i know there are 33 stringsto report. So i did: countResults++;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(countResults / 33 , result); but the divide return 0 all the time. So it's wrong.